# gdb single stepping until exit from function

Tags: c++, cmake, gdb

I'm working on a project which have following architecture.

```
sync
  |--- CMakeLists.txt
  |--- SyncManager
           |---  CMakeLists.txt
           |---  src
  |--- SyncCommon
           |---  CMakeLists.txt
           |---  src
  |--- SyncProcessor
           |---  CMakeLists.txt
           |---  src
```

Both SyncManager and SyncProcessor use functions in SyncCommon.
Contents of CMakeLists.txt are as follow.

sync/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(sync)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

add_subdirectory(SyncManager)
add_subdirectory(SyncProcessor) 
add_subdirectory(SyncCommon)
```

sync/SyncManager/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(SyncManager VERSION 2.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g -O0")

file(GLOB project_SRCS src/*.cpp src/*.h)

include_directories(src/ ../SyncCommon/src)

add_executable(syncManager ${project_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(syncManager syncCommon)
```

sync/SyncCommon/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(ingester VERSION 2.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -g -Wall -O2 -w -fpermissive -pthread")

file(GLOB project_SRCS src/*.cpp src/*.h mhmc/*.c mhmc/*.h)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/cmake/")
find_package(MYSQL REQUIRED)
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

add_library(syncCommon STATIC ${project_SRCS})
target_include_directories(syncCommon 
                           PUBLIC
                           ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
                           ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                           ${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                   
)
target_link_libraries(syncCommon ${CURL_LIBRARIES} ${MYSQL_LIBRARY})
```

sync/SyncProcessor/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(SyncProcessor VERSION 2.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -std=c++11 -Wall -O2 -w -g -O0 -fpermissive -pthread")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

file(GLOB project_SRCS src/*.cpp src/*.h)
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

include_directories(src/ ../SyncCommon/src)

add_executable(syncProcessor ${project_SRCS})
target_include_directories(syncProcessor 
                           PUBLIC
                           ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
                           ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
target_link_libraries(syncProcessor syncCommon ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
```

Now I'm trying to debug SyncManager. Functions in SyncCommon can be executed step by step. But when it comes to functions in SyncManager, I got this error "single stepping until exit from function". I already updated gdb to newest version, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sync/SyncCommon/CMakeLists.txt` has this:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -g -Wall -O2 -w -fpermissive -pthread")
```

Your `sync/SyncManager/CMakeLists.txt` has this:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g -O0")
file(GLOB project_SRCS src/*.cpp src/*.h)
```

You are using `C` flags, despite having `C++` sources. You should set both `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` *and* `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, or just the latter if you don't have any plain-`C` sources.

P.S. You should also get rid of `-fpermissive` and `-w` -- instead fix your sources so `-fpermissive` is not necessary, and turn on `-Wall` -- it's counter-productive to suppress compiler warnings -- you'll just spend longer debugging problems the compiler would have told you about.

Comment: I replaced CMAKE_C_FLAGS with CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, and it works now. Thanks for your answer.